# Get input text value on jQuery keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get input value after keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795283/jquery-get-input-value-after-keypress)

I'm trying to get an `input text` value on `jQuery` `.keypress()` function. I've seen various examples with keypress and keydown, but not dedicated on getting the input value.
Is it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_field").keydown (function (e) {
        alert (e);
    });
});
```

The returned object has a series of properties but I haven't seen something for value input field attribute.

Is there some way to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to get a input text value

Use the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$("#my_field").keydown (function (e) {
    alert ($(this).val());
});
```

Assuming that `#my_field` is the id of input field you want to get the value of.

Comment: @Vittorio Vittori: You are welcome :)

Comment: This will not include the character that was just pressed.

Comment: Inside the keydown function, add this for including the just pressed key
setTimeout(function() {
console.log($('#search').val())
}, 5)

Comment: pure javascript.
var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
alert(c)

Comment: As @superjoe30 said, it won't include the character that was just pressed. The real solution is to get the value of the input on `keyup` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795283/jquery-get-input-value-after-keypress

Comment: In order to get the best result, and thus getting the LAST character entered, use keyup instead. http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ Keyup is fired AFTER the last character is entered, whereas keydown  is entered BEFORE the last character is entered.

Answer (score 13):

I'm unclear which you're after here, in case you're after the letter pressed, not the whole value, you can use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/fromCharCode), for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_field").keydown (function (e) {
     alert (String.fromCharCode(e.which));
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cWHM3/)

Comment: When I try to type numbers from the keypad, it's not the same result as if I were to type the numbers not from the keypad..

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_field').keydown(function(e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want the whole input field value look at this where your alert is:

```
$(this).val()
```