# jquery keypress retrieve value immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to get the contents of an input box using jquery.keypress and I saw an answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430628/get-input-text-value-on-jquery-keypress-event). But that doesn't work as I need it to.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" size="15" maxlength="50">
```

The jquery code looks like this:

```
$("#foo").keypress (function (e) {
    alert ($(this).val());
});
```

So now I have an input box. I type "a". My alert is blank since the handler is retrieving the PREVIOUS contents of '#foo'. Now if I type 'b', the alert will have "a" instead of "ab" and so on. Have a look at this jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gdanko/HWGzz/) and you will see where my problem lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible. The keypress event is triggered before the letter is put in the input box. Try setting a timeout or using the keyup event.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `keyup` instead of `keypress`.