# jQuery get input value after keypress

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dSuggest").keypress(function() {
        var dInput = $('input:text[name=dSuggest]').val();
        console.log(dInput);
        $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

For some reason, for the first keypress, I'm getting an empty string to the console log.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This is because `keypress` events are fired *before* the new character is added to the `value` of the element (so the first `keypress` event is fired before the first character is added, while the `value` is still empty). You should use `keyup` instead, which is fired *after* the character has been added.

Note that, if your element `#dSuggest` is the same as `input:text[name=dSuggest]` you can simplify this code considerably (and if it isn't, having an element with a name that is the same as the `id` of another element is not a good idea).

```
$('#dSuggest').keypress(function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    console.log(dInput);
    $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: Works, but with jquery 2.x out this is out of date now as the answer below using the on and input is the best way to do it now.

Comment: @ppumkin: Just because jQuery 2 is out, doesn't mean people don't need to support IE8 and lower. And I don't see anything in the docs that suggests actual support for the `input` event type.

Comment: You correct, they should stop supporting IE, point. Most "workarounds" in jQuery 1.x are for IE, so it should really be renamed to jQuerIE.

Answer (score 225):

Realizing that this is a rather old post, I'll provide an answer anyway as I was struggling with the same problem.

You should use the `"input"` event instead, and register with the `.on` method. This is fast - without the lag of `keyup` and solves the missing latest keypress problem you describe.

```
$('#dSuggest').on("input", function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    console.log(dInput);
    $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/oleto5/507/edit)

Comment: This should be marked as a proper answer - keyup maybe solves missing character problem, but is problematic to determine if character was actually written (and the key wasn't for example "tab" or "home").

+1 for you

Comment: The problem is that it not is supported in old browsers and IE9 don't respond to deleted characters.

Answer (score 37):

Use `.keyup` instead of keypress.

Also use `$(this).val()` or just `this.value` to access the current input value.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/LXQxy/)** here

Info about `.keypress` from jQuery docs,

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except in the
>   case of key repeats. If the user presses and holds a key, a keydown
>   event is triggered once, but separate keypress events are triggered
>   for each inserted character. In addition, modifier keys (such as
>   Shift) trigger keydown events but not keypress events.

Comment: `keyup` is too slow, and a key can be pressed and held without being released and things must happen. better to use `keydown` with a little timeout so the value actually changes.

Comment: the only downside I've found is that if the user pressed more than one keyboard character together, it will not register correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a ES6 example (so it could pass my linter)
So for other people who are looking for the same:

```
$('#dSuggest').keyup((e) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
});
```

I would also use keyup because you get the current value that is filled in.

Answer (score 5):

You have to interrupt the execution thread to allow the input to update.

```
  $(document).ready(function(event) {
       $("#dSuggest").keypress(function() {
           //Interrupt the execution thread to allow input to update
               setTimeout(function() {
                   var dInput = $('input:text[name=dSuggest]').val();
                   console.log(dInput);
                   $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
               }, 0);
       });
  });
```

Comment: `keyup` delay is too slow for some purposes, and also doesn't auto-filter modifier keys. This actually works better for me.

Comment: best answer. keyup - slow and can not catch chars like @ with two key pressed.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Keypress` event is fired before the new character is added. Use 'keyup' event instead,which will work perfectly in your situation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dSuggest").keyup(function() {
        var dInput = $('input:text[name=dSuggest]').val();
        console.log(dInput);
        $(".dDimension:contains('" + dInput + "')").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

I want to add to this, if you have many textboxes and you have to do the same thing on their keyup event you can simply give them a common css class(eg commoncss) and apply keyup event like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".commoncss").keyup(function() {
        //your code
    });
});
```

this will greatly reduce you code as you don't have to apply keyup event by id for each textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the below prototype

```
$(element).on('input',function(){code})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a timeout to make your call; the timeout will be called when the event stack is finished (i.e. after the default event is called)

```
$("body").on('keydown', 'input[type=tel]', function (e) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        formatPhone(e)
    }, 0)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this code for input text

```
$('#search').on("input",function (e) {});
```

if you use `.on("change",function (e) {});` then you need to blur input

if you use `.on("keyup",function (e) {});` then you get value before the last character you typed

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on('keypress',((e)=>{
 console.log(e.which)
 }))
```

I read the JQuery Documentation (7th June 2023) and it used (e.which) and it returned the ASCII value of the key pressed.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This question did not need this answer, it is already thoroughly answered and this doesn't add to it.