# Javascript TextBox input value is not updating

Tags: javascript

My requirement is on a keypress I need to get the value of the particular textbox. But the problem is when I press the first letter am getting a blank output. on second keypress am getting the first letter which I have entered in the textbox. Form here on Its getting a one step delay. Is am missing anything.

```
 <script>
     document.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
           var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
           if(document.activeElement.id == 'k_id_234'){
                console.log(document.getElementById('k_id_234').value);

           }
     });
   </script>
<input type="text" id="k_id_234">

Text Box : h    console :     // empty
Text Box : he   console : h   //only first letter
.... 
......
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) event instead

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (document.activeElement.id == 'k_id_234') {
        console.log(document.getElementById('k_id_234').value);

    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vLtnum1u/)

- [jQuery get input value after keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795283/jquery-get-input-value-after-keypress)

---

Another option is the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event

Comment: Supporting the answer by @Arun - # keyup(): Event fired when a key is released on the keyboard.
# keydown(): Event fired when a key is pressed on the keyboard.
# keypress:() Event fired when a key is pressed on the keyboard. In case if you press any special key, browser will fire only keydown() event but not keypress() event.