# Passing input element's value as a parameter to a viewmodel function

Tags: knockout.js

What is the syntax (assuming there is one) to pass an `input` control's `value` to a viewmodel function? In my scenario I'm not interested in binding the input's value to a property on the viewmodel. I simply need to act on the value entered into the input control (basically I'm iterating over a collection of items and filtering out those that do not contain the entered text).

```html
<input data-bind="text: filterText($data), valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

I've tried `filterText($data, value)` but Knockout is trying to find `value` property on the viewmodel.  I actually need the current value from the input control.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to handle this use case is to use a [`textInput`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding with a subscription on the bound value that calls `filterText`.

```
<input data-bind="textInput: filter">
```

In your script:

```
filter.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    filterText(newValue)
});
```

which you could simplify to:

```
filter.subscribe(filterText);
```

But you're still probably thinking about this wrong. Your filtered list should be a computed that references the textInput-bound `filter` value to compute the filtered list.

```
filteredList = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    // return the list filtered by the bound filter() value
}, self);
```

Then you can use `filteredList()` wherever you need the filtered list of data.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. Your example code uses [a `text` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) on an `input` node, which isn't all that useful (it would mean a *one-way* binding from view model to DOM, the "text" content of that `input` which is not meaningful). Given the `valueUpdate` binding present you probably meant [the `value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)? Note by the way that [the `textInput` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) is the way to combine those two in modern versions of KnockoutJS.

As to your actual question, important context is missing: *why* do you (think you) want to do this? Depending on the context, the solution will be different, or you might even turn out to have an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In any case, to the answers.

**Option 1**
Trying to answer the specific question nonetheless, I second [@JohnnyHK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243524/419956) of writing a `.subscribe` on your observable as one possible solution.

**Option 2**
Another possible solution closely resembling that one, but trying to satisfy "*I'm not interested in the input's value*" part, I suggest using a read only computed observable:

```js
function Root() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.filter = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return ""; }, // <-- not recommended, read context!
    write: function(newValue) {
      // You're free to discard the newValue   <-- not recommended, read context!
      alert("Input has been changed.");
    }
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="textInput: filter">
```

Now this explicitly discards the `newValue` in the write bit (as per your request), and thus also has a weird-looking `read` function. *I don't recommend this*, and instead would recommend using a private variable with a backing observable for reading and writing. Effectively though, that would make this option equivalent to the first option from the other answer.

An interesting note though, your question's bit about "the collectin" and filtering input: if you look at [the docs from writeable `computed`s](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html) you'll find that accepting users input or not if it satisfies a certain condition *is* in fact a use case for this.

**Option 3**
*What I'd recommend though*, if I rephrase your request a bit:

> How do you react to `input` `value` changes with idiomatic KnockoutJS when your action won't care about the actual `value`?

For writing custom interaction with the DOM, there's [custom binding handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). You could either have one that does not use the ViewModel at all, or one that has an observable.

**Option 3.A**

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["opacitor"] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).on("keydown", function() {
      $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.05 }, 1000, function() { $(this).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000); });
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({});
```

```css
input { background-color: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="opacitor">
```

**Option 3.B**
Or a second option that does use the view model:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers["opacitor"] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    $(element).on("keydown", function() {
      var speed = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor)();
      $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.05 }, speed, function() { $(this).animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, speed); });
    });
  }
}

// speed1 and speed2 could also be observables
ko.applyBindings({ speed1: 500, speed2: 2000 });
```

```css
input { background-color: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="opacitor: speed1">
<input data-bind="opacitor: speed2">
```

The downside of both option 3A and 3B is that you need to write custom event handling logic. If you have a peek at [the `textInput` source from KO](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/textInput.js) you'll see that it's *not trivial* to handle these things correctly cross-browser. So using Option 1 or 2 might still be better (even though you'll have some view model interaction even though "you're not interested").

**Option 4**
Use [the `event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html). This suffers from the same drawbacks as option 3, but might be a straightforward solution nonetheless. Here's an example:

```js
function Root(){
  var self = this;
  self.myFn = function(data, element) {
    console.log(element.target.value);
    return true;
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new Root());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="event: { keyup: myFn }">
```

One subtle change you'll see in that last one, and a question I want to end with: did you in fact not have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795323/419956), where you actually need the *new* value and thus should not be looking at `afterkeydown` but for a different event?

Answer (score 1):

Use $element.value to access the value of  the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not binding the property to the view-model then you can use jquery/javascript to get the value of that input control directly inside your view-model function by doing something like this.

```
self.Filter= function () {           
   var filter = $('#textBoxID').val();
   //    
}
```

This way you do not need to pass the value to your view-model function parameter.

Comment: This will not work with OP's view code, which has a `text` binding. Also, assuming a `value` binding, this solution will technically work, but it's not idiomatic KnockoutJS at all relying on a side effect of how KO works internally, and causes problems down the road in my experience.

Comment: But the guy has stated "In my scenario I'm not interested in binding the input's value to a property on the viewmodel." My solution works for his scenario I believe.

Comment: The code posted [does not work with OP's view](https://jsfiddle.net/a1pxenaj/). After fixing all issues (missing `id`, changing `text` to `value`, changing `filter` to `Filter`), fixes that should've been included in the answer, [it'll work](https://jsfiddle.net/7fvqy56w/), and it might solve OP's problem, but it'll be IMHO non-idiomatic knockoutjs code that will cause problems in the long run, and as such is bad advice. The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243524/419956) (with a subscription) is better advice, and I've tried to show some better alternatives in my answer as well.