# Accept only numbers and letters code not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prevent user from entering anything except numbers and letters, but my code doesn't even allow them itself. What could be the reason? Here's my code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtuname").keypress(function(e){ 
        var validExp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/gi;
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val.match(validExp))
        {
            $("#errmsg").html("");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only"); 
            return false;
        }
    });
});


<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinsharma1507/hbo5mkea/1/)

Comment: use html 5 pattern istead.

Comment: It would be good idea to debug code and [edit] post with values you getting...

Comment: @Nasir: No, not every versions of all top ranking browsers support it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Can't you see the demo at JSFiddle. It will show you what I'm seeing exactly on my local?

Comment: Essentially you are saying "I'm too lazy to provide useful information in the post - deal with it" - this is not be the best way to take care of posts.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: why are you so angry with me? Those are your own words. I merely said see the demo.

Comment: @user5307298 Should paste of characters which are not 0-9a-z be allowed at element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#txtuname").keypress(function (e) {

            var validExp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/gi;

            if (validExp.test(e.key)) {
                $("#errmsg").html("");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only");

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This guy has come up with most efficient answer. It's simple and main thing it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup`  not `keypress`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#txtuname").keyup(function(e){ 
  var validExp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/gi;
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val.match(validExp))
  {
   $("#errmsg").html("");
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only"); 
   return false;
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Comment: The forbidden characters still show up in the input box despite the warning. So you will want to use `keydown`, instead of `keyup`

Comment: Your solution is buggy as well whether you do use keyup or keydown; doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute `input` event for `keypress` event; adjust `RegExp` to `/[0-9a-z]/i`, use `.split()` with parameter `""`, `Array.prototype.every()`, `RegExp.prototype.test()` to check each character of input value at `if` condition; if each character is a digit or a letter condition is `true`, else `false` replace invalid characters of `value` using `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/[^0-9a-z]/ig`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var validExp = /[0-9a-z]/i;
      $("#txtuname").on("input", function(e) {
        var val = this.value;
        var check = val.split("").every(function(value) {
          return validExp.test(value)
        });
        if (check) {
          $("#errmsg").html("");
          return check;
        } else {
          this.value = val.replace(/[^0-9a-z]/ig, "");
          $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only");
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Comment: You may want to highlight actual answer (`keyup`) as well as mention `paste` as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35592412/477420

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov See updated post. `input` event handles paste of characters at `<input>` element

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Re-read Question. Must have missed that characters should be removed from input. Added call to `.replace()` to replace characters which are not a-z0-9

Answer (score 0):

This is because keypress events are fired before the new character is added to the value of the element (so the first keypress event is fired before the first character is added, while the value is still empty). You should use keyup instead, which is fired after the character has been added [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8795323/2169925).

Here is the code

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtuname").keyup(function(e){ 
        var validExp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/gi;
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val.match(validExp))
        {
            $("#errmsg").html("");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only"); 
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I already commented on this in other people's solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is you are not getting the value of the key that is being pressed. If you set the `val` variable like so, it will work as expected.

```
var val = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
```

This gets the ASCII code of the key pressed, and then converting to the letter or number it represents. Then you can check against your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtuname").keyup(function(e){ 
        var validExp = /^[0-9a-z]+$/gi;
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(validExp.test(val))
        {
            $("#errmsg").html("");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // fix the value of input field here 
            $(this).val("");
            $("#errmsg").html("Number and letters Only"); 
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtuname" id="txtuname" />
<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

1. You need to use keyup so that the character is "added" already to the value if you're going to use this given technique.
2. Since `String.prototype.match`  actually returns an array of the match, it won't work in the way you want it to. Not to mention that it is much more expensive than `RegEx.prototype.test`.

### Bonus

You can use the technique of finding carret position in an input field shown in [Get cursor position (in characters) within a text Input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897155/get-cursor-position-in-characters-within-a-text-input-field)

To actually fix the input field on keyup.